# Reference different assets based on build flavor

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am able to get the correct `api_key.txt` on `debug` builds because that is a `buildType`. However I am unable to get this working with the productFlavor `amazon`.

I’ve tried doing this in my `build.gradle` file which compiles but it will not actually reference the correct file at run time:

```
sourceSets {
amazon {
  assets.srcDirs = ['app/src/amazon/assets']
}
```

Here is my folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

How can I reference `api_key.txt` in the `amazon/assets` folder when my product flavor is `amazon`?

All help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: How are you building your amazon flavor?

Comment: you don't need to add `assets.srcDirs = ['app/src/amazon/assets']`. Try removing it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on this https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants document you want this type of hierarchy structure of your application.
Remove `assets.srcDirs` from all build flavours and you can try with this kind of structure.

```
buildTypes {
  release {
    // ... the usual stuff here
  }
  releaseAlt {
    // .. the usual stuff here too like signing config etc...
  }
}
```

file hierarchy You should have like :

```
project/
- app/
 - src/
  - main/
   - assets/
    - logo.png // Generic assets go here
   - java/
   - res/
   - ...

  - flavor1/
   - assets/
    - logo.png // Specific assets for all the flavor1 Variants

  - release/
   - assets/
    - logo.png // Specific assets for all the releaseAlt Variants.

  - flavor1Release/
   - assets/
    - logo.png // very specific assets for the flavor1ReleaseAlt Variant
- SDK/
```

Comment: Since the build type overrides the flavor, I just made my folder `amazonRelease` and that did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think you should write "src/amazon/assets" instead of "app/src/amazon/assets".

```
sourceSets {
amazon {
  assets.srcDirs = ['/src/amazon/assets']
}
```

Comment: Note: you'd likely want `assets.srcDirs = ['src/amazon/assets']` without the forward slash at the beginning.