# How to get dynamic values from product flavor into a properties file

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I'm developing a Flutter application with different product flavors for Android and want to be able to define a value for each flavor, and select the value based on which flavor I'm building, and interpolate it into a properties file in order to dynamically configure a third party library.  I would also be open to having multiple duplicate properties files, each with their flavor-specific values, and then selecting the right one at build time.

My research suggests I'm likely taking the wrong approach.  After reading the Android documentation, I tried using BuildConfig to generate the values and then reference them in the properties file.  I do see that the BuildConfig.java is built with the right values, but they are not being interpolated in my properties file.  I'm not sure what approach I should be taking here, so any suggestions would be great!

**thirdPartyLibrary.properties**

```java
customProperty=${BuildConfig.CUSTOM_PROPERTY}
```

**build.gradle**

```
...

flavorDimensions "app"

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "app"
            buildConfigField "String", "CUSTOM_PROPERTY", "\"my custom property for dev\""
        }
        qa {
            dimension "app"
            buildConfigField "String", "CUSTOM_PROPERTY", "\"my custom property for qa\""
        }
    }
    
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct thing to do here was to simply create duplicate configuration files for each flavor and place the flavor-specific properties files in the correct folder for the flavor, so that it is copied to the correct "build/app/intermediates/merged_assets" folder.  So instead of having a single "src/main/assets/thirdPartyLibrary.properties" file, I now have two files, one for dev and one for QA:
"src/dev/assets/thirdPartyLibrary.properties"
"src/qa/assets/thirdPartyLibrary.properties"

This is so painfully obvious once you understand how Android's build system works, but was initially opaque to me as a new Flutter developer.

This is the thread that pointed me at the right answer: [Reference different assets based on build flavor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50382148/reference-different-assets-based-on-build-flavor)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by following the steps outlined here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47992042/4215892

So I removed the values from my properties file, and instead added this code to the gradle file:

```
...

def thirdPartyLibraryProperties = new Properties()
File thirdPartyConfig = file("src/main/assets/thirdPartyLibrary.properties")

flavorDimensions "app"

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "app"
            thirdPartyLibraryProperties.load(thirdPartyConfig.newDataInputStream())
            thirdPartyLibraryProperties.setProperty("customProperty", "my custom property for dev")
            thirdPartyLibraryProperties.store(thirdPartyConfig.newWriter(), null)
        }
        qa {
            dimension "app"
            thirdPartyLibraryProperties.load(thirdPartyConfig.newDataInputStream())
            thirdPartyLibraryProperties.setProperty("customProperty", "my custom property for qa")
            thirdPartyLibraryProperties.store(thirdPartyConfig.newWriter(), null)
        }
    }
    
    ...
```

However this feels like I'm repeating myself unnecessarily and like there is probably a cleaner solution.  It is also modifying a file that is in source and not the build destination, which is generally bad practice.