# React Native - How do I structure my Mobile Application so I use a single codebase, and can have multiple white labelled apps branched off?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Problem Set: I've developed a Mobile Application with React Native. I now need to White-label / copy and paste to different customers. Each customer may have different features based on their subscription. I want to essentially have a Single / Core code base with features, that can be built and fixed independently and the Apps just "import" functionality from the core.

If I Fix one component in the core, I should be able to update all my white-labeled apps but all apps can also have their own skin/color/functionality as well. I think this is better to maintain long-term in terms of development. Its not a simple Skin but also features added / removed are based on the customer.

This is easier in Python but I am new to React native - Looking for advice on the tools and techniques available.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar kind of problem set while developing a white label app.

### Here are my project requirements:

- Localization
- Theme customization
- Login Flow

### I implemented a white label solution in the following way:

Let's say we have two customers i.e. `Dine Out` & `Zomato`.

- Create the main app flow i.e. the features which will be shared across the multiple apps in `react-native`.
- Make sure that you write the code configuration using flags/values and make reusable components.
  Ex: let's say `Dine Out` only accepting parcel `take away` not delivery but `Zomato` does so. Similarly `Dine Out` has a black colour navigation bar but `Zomato` likes brighter.
- Make configurable item's keys are same for all the apps.

---

### Main White Label Configuration at Native Side:

## iOS:

In terms of `XCode`, we can consider the `Zomato` & `Dine Out` as two different `Targets` in `Xcode`. So create two `Targets` & create the build configuration to set the multiple environments i.e. debug, release.

[image]

From the above image, you can see that there are two targets under the `TARGETS` section. And five `Build Configuration` under `Build Active Architecture Only`.

[image: no description]

- Create two directories from the project navigator section & paste the configuration files & target assets.

[image]

- Select all the files from the target directory and only check the target for which you have added the assets & files from the `Inspector` section.

---

## Android:

In terms of `Android Studio`, we can consider the `Zomato` & `Dine Out` as two different `Flavors`. So create two apps `Flavors` & create the `buildTypes` to set the multiple environments i.e. debug, release in app-level `build.gradle` file.

[image]

[image]

- Create two directories from at `./app/src/` path with the name same as build flavour names & paste the configuration files & target assets. After doing this, you will have a directory structure like the below image.

[image]

You can find detailed configuration for android from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50390875/7210270).

---

## React Native:

If you have followed all the steps till here then you are done with configuration from the native side. Now you only need to access the values related to `Target`/`Flavour` in `react-native`.

There are some important libraries in React Native that can help to fetch the values from native to React Native environment.

1. `react-native-build-config`: From the above image in the `Android` section you will see a `buildConfigField` field `APP_ENVIRONMENT` of type `String`. You can access this variable value by using this library in React Native i.e. `BuildConfig.APP_ENVIRONMENT`. Similarly, you can add the `APP_ENVIRONMENT` variable in iOS as shown in the below image.

[image]

2. `react-native-fs`: Use this if you are keeping configuration in JSON file in native directories. In above configuration, I kept `PilotConfig.json` file which can be accessed in React Native using `fetch('PilotConfig.json`) for iOS & `RNFS.readFileAssets('PilotConfig.json')` for Android.
3. `react-native-localize`: You can use this library for loading locales. It also provides a listener in case the user changes the device language.

---

Rest everything is at the logic part in `JavaScript`, how you implement.

> Multiple `Firebase` apps can also be configured using `build script`.

Comment: can you speak a bit more to how Firebase projects can be configured for android? It's easy for iOS you just attach different credential files to different targets in XCode. Not entirely sure how to do it for android seeing as they require a certain file name in the root folder.

Comment: @ChristopherReid
I assume you have 2 build configuration i.e. `alpha` & `gamma` and want to configure different firebase projects for both of them.
Then you would require to create 2 directory with same name as flavour i.e. `alpha` & `gamma` inside `app/src/` directory of android project. And paste respective `google-service.json` files in it. So whenever you will run the project it will automatically pick the desired file according to flavour you are running.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a monorepo approach and build from libs. I'd recommend you checkout [nx](https://nx.dev) by nrwl.

Answer (score 0):

I will start with a config file. e.g: config.base.js (JSON)
Then override the base confi with: config.custom.js

And each customer will have their own config.<customer_id>.js file
when you build, you can copy the customer config file to overwrite config.custom.js

Example how to load config into app

```
let baseConfig = require("./config.base.json");
const customConfig = require("./config.custom.js");

appConfig = Object.assign(baseConfig, customConfig);

export const FEATURES_ENABLED: [{id: string}: boolean] = appConfig.features;
```

The app code will depend on FEATURES_ENABLED to render

Answer (score 0):

For your situation, I suggest you to **create your own npm package** for your app core features:

#### Benefits:

- You can update/fix your core inside the package project instead of every single app project
- If you want to update the core for existing production apps, just `npm install` again or update your package version
- Have better versioning control on your core code
- If your core codes don't have any business logic, you can **open-source it and let other developers use and improve it together (optional)**

---

### Therefore...

If you don't want to expose your core codes, just create it as a **private npm package**: [document](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-private-packages)

Or if you are ok to **open source it as a public package**: [document](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-scoped-public-packages)

Cheers!