# Is different assets based on flavor supported by Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to include an asset based on flavor of app in flutter. I can see its implementation in android [Reference different assets based on build flavor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50382148/reference-different-assets-based-on-build-flavor) but couldn't make it work for flutter. Asset is throwing a 'Not found' error.

If anyone could provide inputs if there are different configuration for flutter to use it. We are using flutter sdk 3.3.8.